# blank space as padding char when importing table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, char, ssms

I have a flat file where data is separated by a blank char:

```
a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9 a10...a21
485 477 537 479 452 471 491 476 475 473 455 500 456 507 478 491 447 422 480 482 515
482 464 484 477 496 509 491 459 482 483 505 508 458 509 517 479 487 473 472 474 531
485 508 517 489 507 515 440 465 550 532 450 483 460 469 507 485 479 458 516 480 460
479 648 480 561 481 474 474 544 484 490 451 494 480 486 459 521 500 466 457 494 492 
188 497 477 461 473 464 476 471 481 507 474 500 481 536 464 501 479 480 483 462 470 
....
181 510 470 431 482 496 481 469 539 491 482 481 476 533 495 474 485 479 495 465 541
```

How do I import it in SQL Server 2008, I do not find any option to use blank char as padding char...I have seen Carriage return CR,  Carriage Return/Linefeed (CR/LF), TAB...etc...

I am using Microsoft SQL Management Studio...

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a valid option for you or not, but since nobody else is answering, here goes... Personally, being lazy, I'd whip up a quick and dirty .NET Console app to convert it into a .csv file.  It'd be faster for me than searching for a solution on importing it as-is.  I may even just do it in C# and read the contents into a DataTable and use the SQLBulkCopy method to update the server if it's something I have to do over and over again and have to automate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open "`New Query Window`" in `SQL Management Studio`
- Copy Paste this data to a new query window
- Open `Find/Replace` Window (`CTR+SHIFT+H`)
- Find Options: `"Use RegEx"`
- In "Find" specify: `:b`
- In "Replace": `\t`
- Press "Replace All"

This will replace all spaces by tabs

More details about [Visual Studio/Management Studio built in RegEx support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I was just doing that in Notepad++!!

Comment: I would suggest you to study such simple RegEx this will work for you and save your time ;)

Comment: That's funny!  That's even easier than my idea, and I thought I Was taking the easy way out.  +1 to you.

Comment: @David Stratton: Thanks David!